# How to validate the attributes which starts with @ in postman JS tests

Tags: postman, postman-testcase

I need to validate the value of "@type" attribute in the below response through POSTMAN JS tests.but when am trying to write tests am getting a syntax error(Invalid or unexpected token)

JS Test line:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
console.log(jsonData.ErrorResponse.Result.Error[0].@type)
```

Response:

```
{
    "ErrorResponse": {
        "Result": {
            "Error": [
                {
                    "@type": "ErrorDetail",
                    "StatusCode": "400",                    
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use bracket notation `["@type"]` to access that value:

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();

console.log(jsonData.ErrorResponse.Result.Error[0]['@type'])
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors